# Automatic registration of static object factories inside dll modules via metaprogramming or other

Tags: c++, dll, factory-pattern

In a project I am working on I want to put classes into a dll that will be initialized by an abstract factory and included via composition within objects in the main program. The purpose is to allow users to create their own dll modules and thus add their own functionality. The dll module itself should be as simple as possible; ideally it would just contain the functionality classes and their base class. The user only has access to the source for the dll and not the main program or factory.

I found some code for an abstract factory on codeproject.com that seems pretty good to me. Here's the example code:

Code:

```
// Templates for the generic factory and factory plant
template <class BT>
class FactoryPlant
   {
   public:
      FactoryPlant() {}
      virtual ~FactoryPlant() {}
      virtual BT *createInstance() = 0;
   };

template <class BT,class ST>
class Factory : public FactoryPlant<BT>
   {
   public:
      Factory() {}
      virtual ~Factory() {}
      virtual BT *createInstance() {return new ST;}
   };


// Our sample classes
class SimpleBaseClass
   {
   public:
      virtual int              getValue()          = 0;
      virtual void             setValue(int value) = 0;
      typedef FactoryPlant<SimpleBaseClass> SimpleBaseClassFactory;
   };

class SimpleClass1 : public SimpleBaseClass
   {
   public:
      int  getValue()          {return m_value;}
      void setValue(int value) {m_value = value;}
      static Factory<SimpleBaseClass,SimpleClass1> myFactory;
   private:
      int m_value;
   };
Factory<SimpleBaseClass,SimpleClass1> SimpleClass1::myFactory;

class SimpleClass2 : public SimpleBaseClass
   {
   public:
      int  getValue()          {return m_value*100;}
      void setValue(int value) {m_value = value;}
      static Factory<SimpleBaseClass,SimpleClass2> myFactory;
   private:
      int m_value;
   };
Factory<SimpleBaseClass,SimpleClass2> SimpleClass2::myFactory;

// Some method that might need to create an instance
SimpleBaseClass *someMethod (std::map<int,SimpleBaseClass::SimpleBaseClassFactory *> factories, int type)
{
return factories[type]->createInstance();
}

void main()
{
SimpleBaseClass                                         *simpleInstance     = NULL;
std::map<int,SimpleBaseClass::SimpleBaseClassFactory *>  factories;

factories[1] = &SimpleClass1::myFactory;
factories[2] = &SimpleClass2::myFactory;

simpleInstance = someMethod (factories,1);
if (simpleInstance)
   {
   simpleInstance->setValue (123);
   std::cout << simpleInstance->getValue() << std::endl;
   delete simpleInstance;
   }
else
   {
   std::cout << "Instance creation failed" << std::endl;
   }

simpleInstance = someMethod (factories,2);
if (simpleInstance)
   {
   simpleInstance->setValue (123);
   std::cout << simpleInstance->getValue() << std::endl;
   delete simpleInstance;
   }
else
   {
   std::cout << "Instance creation failed" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

The obvious way to do this is to have a registration function inside each dll that gets called to build up the map. My question: is it possible to have my program register the factories in the map automatically somehow eg. through some metaprogramming technique so that the user doesn't need to make this function, which could potentially have a very long list of map assignments? What I want to do would be something like make a list or script of the dll classes at compile time and then perform registration from the list at runtime.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using global object constructors for such registrations. Being linked with proper C++ linker, dynamic libraries call those constructors at module initialization. Destructors are also useful - you can perform unregistration there.

So the idea is - use global map containing all loaded factories. Fill it from the constructor of some global object defined in each library.

In Visual Studio you might need to force linker not to optimize out an instance object with constructor. This may be done by exporting the global variable in question.

Comment: There are risks to static (gloabl) constructors.  See these links:

[link](http://www.nsnam.org/docs/linker-problems.doc)
[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/b0ac6c6b-b56e-4197-8eb7-2931a8350554/)
[link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12)  
 "“Statically linking a program that uses global or static constructors and destructors in C++ can be a confusing and sometimes tricky proposition.  The simplest answer is a common recommendation:  just don’t do it."

Comment: The question is about dynamic linking, isn't it? Exported symbols are always there, linker can't eliminate them. We can't tell much about static initialization order, but we know that components are loaded later than the registration service, and that's all we need. BTW, MS format are hard to read.

Comment: As I said, there are risks, even in case of dynamic linking. For example, if the DLL is composed from LIBs you need to be careful not to put your global object constructors in the LIBs, as this will not work in a straightforward way.

Comment: Can you further explain the LIBs problem? Why our single, independent on others, dynamically exported global object will have initialization difficulties? I'm not trying to defend my approach, I just want to get better understanding of those nuances.

Comment: The LIB problem happens when the linker assumes that no code from a compilation unit is used and ignores any global or static constructors in that compilation unit. If the object is exported this won't happen, but then, is the purpose of exporting the global object is only to ensure this? The global object is only created for its static constructor.   This is a hack very much like specifying #pragma comment(linker, "/INCLUDE:...") used for the same purpose. At least edit your post and mention that this "global object defined in each library" must be known to the linker by some hack.

Comment: Done. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by requiring each such DLL export two simple functions

```
void getAvailableComponents(std::list<string> &components);
IComponent *getComponent(const std::string &componentName);
```

Here `getComponentFactory` can return either an instance of the class containing the additional functionality or a lightweight factory that creates one. What IComponent does, how it behaves and how you deal with various class types is really up to you and how much of your environment you want to expose.

Note that to access these functions from your program you will need to pass their *decorated* names to GetProcAddress()